# MATLAB Plus Error Bars?

Tags: matlab

How can I make MATLAB error bars that only go above the mean in a bar graph or histogram? The errorbar function only gives symmetric bars

Thanks! This is easy to do on Excel but I cannot find a way to conveniently do so on MATLAB

Comment: @A.Donda Thanks for catching my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the third form of [`errorbar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbar.html) that allows you to specify both upper `U` and lower `L` error bars, and set the lower to 0:

```
x = 1:10;
y = 10*rand(1,10);
U = rand(1,10);
L = zeros(size(y));

errorbar(x, y, L, U)
```

[image]